# Using Checkboxes to Update a MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, sql-update

Ok, I know I'll probably get bashed for even asking this... its been about 5-6 years since I've touched PHP and MySql, so I think I may be overthinking all of this.

I have an HTML form, that is a series of checkboxes, and by clicking one, I would like it to set it's relative entry in the database to 0 or 1. When the update is complete, it returns to the form so I can change the settings again if needed.

The amount of entries (checkboxes) will be a static amount will be static, so I don't think a foreach loop will be necessary, I'm more or less trying to jog my memory on how to work with PHP, and I'm not having much luck reading a whole mess of answers scattered about SO that kinda have to deal with what I'm trying to do.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**FORM:**

```
<?php

 require "config.php";

 $db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

 $query = "SELECT * FROM roster";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

?>
<form action="update.php"  method="POST">
<?php

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
            $active = $row['active'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $class = $row['class'];
            $value = '0';

            if ($active == '1'){
                $value = '0';
            } else {
                $value = '1';
            }

            echo "<label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' name='".$class."' value='". $value."'";

            if($active == '1'){
                echo "checked='checked'";
            }

            echo "/><div class='slider'></div><span>" . $name . "</span></label>";
        }

 mysql_close();
 ?>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Update Active Roster">
</form>
```

**Update.php (so far) - this is where I need help, I think**

```
<?php
require "config.php";

$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$checkbox = $_POST['activate'];
for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($checkbox)+1; $i++){
    $query = "UPDATE roster SET active='".$checkbox[$i]."' WHERE id='".$i."'";
    echo "active='".$checkbox[$i]."' WHERE id='".$i."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

**MySQL Database**

```
id   class      name         active
0    thisdude   This Dude    0
1    thatguy    That Guy     0
2    somechick  Some Chick   0
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery and Ajax will solve it easily.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='".$class."' value='". $value."'"; class="mycheckbox" />
```

Now send ajax call when the user check it, where update_datase.php file can contain the update query.

```
$('.mycheckbox').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("value"));  //-->this will alert value that will be update to DB.
       if(this.checked){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'update_databse.php',
                data: $(this).attr("value"),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('DB updated');
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                }
            });

            }
      });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Although it may answer the question on how to return back to the page, it isn't updating the database at all. I also wonder why you are adding a class to each checkbox, when I could just call a input[type=checkbox] and why you are calling alerts, when I should be calling console.log().  My update script is what needs attention most of all, which I have illustrated above.